# How to mock class inside another class that being tested?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, mocking

I'm trying to write an integration test for authentification with Spring Security and JWT. My problem is that during authentification in authentification filter it checks that user is valid in the external system. How can I mock class that makes calls to external system during the test?

Here is a security config:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthService authService;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    } 

    @Bean
    public AuthentificationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthentificationTokenFilter(authService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I need to mock `AuthService` inside `AuthentificationTokenFilter` where actual authentification is happening, but I don't directly interact with it and security config. I only trying to make a rest request to `RestController` and if authentification is correct then this request should return `200` code.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to mock it using Mockito? Use the advantage of [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) and the annotation [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) to distinguish the `AuthService` interface implementation for the `test` and other environments.

```
@Service
@Profile("test")
public class MockAuthService implements AuthService {

    // ... the mock implementation
}
```

Comment: It only has one method that returns true or false, so I thought to mock it will be easier, but by doing it with profiles it will be easier to add it in every test

Comment: @user2452483: Yes, with this approach you might control more of the implementations (against in-memory data, against the dev. database or another one...). I feel this way is easier to test and mainly, you focus on the testing itself than mocking.